# I2C Problem on STM32F4 Discovery connecting to CS43L22

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, stm32, stm32f4, i2s

I'm trying to use the internal beep generator of [CS43L22](https://www.cirrus.com/cn/pubs/proDatasheet/CS43L22_F2.pdf) on my STM32F4 Discovery. I'm using the HAL libary and can access the Chip via I2C but only for 4 Bytes (read or write) then the function `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit()` gets stuck.

I narrowed the stuck down to `I2C_WaitOnMasterAddressFlagUntilTimeout()` Lines(5084 to 5122) in stm32f4xx_hal_i2c.c. When using a stepwise debugging, the complete code works fine, running from Breaktpoint to Breakpoint it fails.

I'm using Keil µVision 5.15 and would like to use the HAL drivers as the project will get ported to a RTOS application.
If you need any other information I will be happy to provide it.

What could cause the code to get stuck? And what to do to prevent it?

my main.c:

```
// main.c

#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "my_header.h"


int main(void){

    I2C_HandleTypeDef I2C_Params; // declare Parameter Handle
    I2S_HandleTypeDef I2S_Params; // declare Parameter Handle
    HAL_StatusTypeDef I2C_State; // declare State handle
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIOD_Params; // Declares the structure handle for the parameters of the reset pin on GPIOE
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIOB_Params; // Declares the structure handle for the parameters of I2C on GPIOB
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIOC_Params; // Declares the structure handle for the parameters of I2S on GPIOC
    uint8_t send_data; // declare send data variable
    uint8_t send_data_array[2]; // declare send data variable
    uint8_t received_data; // declare received data variable

    HAL_Init(); // Initialise  Hal driver

    // configure System Clock
    RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;

  /* Enable Power Control clock */
  __PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* The voltage scaling allows optimizing the power consumption when the device is 
     clocked below the maximum system frequency, to update the voltage scaling value 
     regarding system frequency refer to product datasheet.  */
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /* Enable HSE Oscillator and activate PLL with HSE as source */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 336;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 7;
  HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct);

  /* Select PLL as system clock source and configure the HCLK, PCLK1 and PCLK2 
     clocks dividers */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = (RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2);
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;  
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;  
  HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_5);


    LED_Init(); // initialise LEDs
    Set_State_Rd_LED(1); // turn on red LED


    // Configure GPIOD for reset pin on CS43L22
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIODEN; //Enable the clock for GPIOD
    GPIOD_Params.Pin = GPIO_PIN_4; // Select pin 4
    GPIOD_Params.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP; //Selects normal output push-pull mode
    GPIOD_Params.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FAST; //Selects fast speed
    GPIOD_Params.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN; //Selects pull-down activation
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIOD_Params); // Sets GPIOD into the modes specified in GPIOE_Params


    // Configure GPIOB for SCL (PB6) and SDA (PB9) on I2C1
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOBEN; //Enable the clock for GPIOA
    GPIOB_Params.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6 | GPIO_PIN_9; // Selects pins 6 and 9
    GPIOB_Params.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_I2C1; //Selects alternate function (I2C1)
    GPIOB_Params.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD; //Selects alternate function open drain mode
    GPIOB_Params.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FAST; //Selects fast speed
    //GPIOB_Params.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH; //Selects fast speed
    GPIOB_Params.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL; //Selects no pull-up or pull-down activation
    //GPIOB_Params.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP; //Selects no pull-up activation
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIOB_Params); // Sets GPIOB into the modes specified in GPIOA_Params


    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_I2C1EN  ; // Enables the clock for I2C1
    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_SPI3EN  ; // Enables the clock for SPI3 (I2S)


    // Configure GPIOC for 7(MCLK), 10(SCLK) and 12(SDIN) on I2S
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOBEN; //Enable the clock for GPIOA
    GPIOC_Params.Pin = GPIO_PIN_7 | GPIO_PIN_10 | GPIO_PIN_12; // Selects pins 7(MCLK), 10(SCLK) and 12(SDIN)
    GPIOC_Params.Alternate = GPIO_AF6_SPI3; //Selects alternate function (I2C1)
    GPIOC_Params.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP; //Selects alternate function open drain mode
    GPIOC_Params.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FAST; //Selects fast speed
    GPIOC_Params.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL; //Selects no pull-up or pull-down activation
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIOC_Params); // Sets GPIOB into the modes specified in GPIOA_Params

    I2S_Params.Instance = SPI3; 
    I2S_Params.Init.Mode = I2S_MODE_MASTER_TX;
    I2S_Params.Init.Standard = I2S_STANDARD_PHILIPS;
    I2S_Params.Init.DataFormat = I2S_DATAFORMAT_16B;
    I2S_Params.Init.MCLKOutput = I2S_MCLKOUTPUT_ENABLE;
    I2S_Params.Init.AudioFreq = I2S_AUDIOFREQ_48K;
    I2S_Params.Init.CPOL = I2S_CPOL_LOW;
    //I2S_Params.Init.ClockSource = I2S_CLOCK_PLL;
    //I2S_Params.Init.FullDuplexMode = I2S_FULLDUPLEXMODE_DISABLE;
    HAL_I2S_Init(&I2S_Params);


    // Configure I2C
    I2C_Params.Instance = I2C1;
    I2C_Params.Init.ClockSpeed = 100000; // Set clock speed to 50 kHz
    I2C_Params.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2; // Set duty cycle
    I2C_Params.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0x33; // set own adress 1 
    // I2C_Params.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0x00; // set own adress 1  
    I2C_Params.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT; // set to 7-Bit adresses
    I2C_Params.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLED; // Disabel dual address mode
    I2C_Params.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0; // set own adress 2
    I2C_Params.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLED; // General call disabled
    I2C_Params.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLED; // No Stretch disabled
    // I2C_Params.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_ENABLE; // No Stretch enabled
    // I2C_Params.Mode = HAL_I2C_MODE_MASTER; // set I2C to master
    // HAL_I2C_MspInit(&I2C_Params); // configure I2C
    __HAL_I2C_ENABLE(&I2C_Params); // Enable the I2C1
    I2C_State = HAL_I2C_Init(&I2C_Params); // configure I2C

    __HAL_I2S_ENABLE(&I2S_Params);

    GPIOD->BSRR |= GPIO_PIN_4; //Sets the reset pin of CS43L22 high

    // ceck value
    send_data = 0x01; // address of chip ID
    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&I2C_Params, 0x94, &send_data, 1, 1000); // Write Address to read
    HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&I2C_Params, 0x94, &received_data, 1, 1000); // read Chip ID register

    // ceck value
    send_data = 0x01; // address of chip ID
    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&I2C_Params, 0x94, &send_data, 1, 1000); // Write Address to read
    HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&I2C_Params, 0x94, &received_data, 1, 1000); // read Chip ID register

    I2C_State = HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&I2C_Params, 0x0094, 10, 1000);

    // ceck value
    send_data = 0x01; // address of chip ID
    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&I2C_Params, 0x94, &send_data, 1, 1000); // Write Address to read
    HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&I2C_Params, 0x94, &received_data, 1, 1000); // read Chip ID register

    Set_State_Or_LED(1); // turn on orange LED

};
```

Comment: For the benefit of any readers here who understand German - they can read the duplicate of this question (which is already receiving replies) at: http://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/413574

Comment: I do not know what can be the problem, but if you download [SW4STM32](http://www.st.com/en/development-tools/sw4stm32.html) and you create a C project for an STM32F4Discovery with audiio driver added. Then there will be a ready to use audio driver + application inside the project. You can use that as reference. [Project tree](https://postimg.org/image/stbx74u6n/). You can use it as reference, not that the driver is not written in HAL, just the application.

Answer (score 1):

You never activate the clock for GPIO port C because of copy-paste mistake.

Change this:

```
RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOBEN; //Enable the clock for GPIOA
```

To this:

```
RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOCEN; //Enable the clock for GPIOC
```

The debugger might do this for you and that is the reason why it is working when debugging.